# What follows a mass noun followed by a list with several items?

Tags: plural-forms, singular, uncountable-nouns

1. Equipment are gloves and glasses.
2. Equipment is gloves and glasses.

//The translation has been approved, but I am only the editor, I have to work with grammar, interpunction but cannot change the terms.

Comment: "Equipment is" since equipment is uncountable.

Comment: What is the context before this phrase? Just using "Equipment is" by itself seems odd. I would expect "Equipment *used* is..." or "That equipment is...".

Comment: _"The required equipment for this trip is gloves and glasses."_ (Although I would be more likely to say _"The equipment required for this trip is gloves and glasses.")_

Answer (score 2):

*Equipment is gloves and glasses.*

Equipment is an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 1):

You already said that you know this word as a 'mass noun'. Simply replace this with another mass noun and come up with an answer...

> Knowledge ***[means] OR [mean]*** perception and learning

Certainly it is ***'means'***, isn't it?

So,

> Equipment ***is*** gloves and glasses